# Magento cart sort by category_id

Tags: magento

I am trying to sort out items in cart by categroy_id:

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems()
->addFieldToSelect('name')
->addFieldToSelect('category_id')
->addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'ASC');

 echo $cartItems->getSelect(); //debug info


 foreach($cartItems as $item) {
        echo $this->getItemHtml($item); 
 }
```

Magento complaints that method addAttributeToSort does not exists, had a look and of course it isn't defined.

What is the proper way of doing this query?

Otherwise,

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems()
    ->addFieldToSelect('name')
    ->addFieldToSelect('category_id')
    ->addOrder('category_id', 'asc');
```

`addAttributeToSort()` does work on certain collections, but not the checkout/cart Model.

I hope this helps!

Comment: your right, the addOrder does work but it cannot access the category_id. In my code the category_id is stored deep down inside the items-products-data. Drilling down you can locate the id inside the $collection variable from the code I had posted: $collection => [_items] => [287] => [_data] => [product] => [_data] => [category_ids] [0] => [3]

Answer (score 0):

When you run `Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems()` you get a collection of quote items, not products. So there is no category_id on the table sales_flat_quote_item that you can access.

If you want access to the product you have to loop your collection of quote items and run `->getProduct()` on each item. Then you could call functions on the product, like `->getCategoryIds()` to get a list of category ids that has the product assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks Manne, that explains the missing category_id.

Right now, after getting the ids I'm storing them in an aray that is actually ordered the way I need them. Do you happen to know if it's possible to pass them out to the render function?